# Erratic error No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type Object from content with media type 'text/html'

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.1

I'm calling a rest web service and it's work fine 99% of the time, but whiles in a while I'm receiving the error "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Order' from content with media type 'text/html'"
Here is my code. C# Core 2.1

I'm using IHttpClientFactory to call the service.

```
public APIvtex(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}
```

//and the method inside the class

```
public Order GetOrder(string orderId)
{
    Order OutPut = null;
    string url = "http://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com.br/api/oms/pvt/orders/";
    url = url + orderId;
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("X-VTEX-API-AppKey", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
    request.Headers.Add("X-VTEX-API-AppToken", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = client.SendAsync(request);
    response.Wait();
    if (response.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var task = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Order>();
        task.Wait();
        OutPut = task.Result;
    }
return OutPut;
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems rather fishy to me that your request ask for `application/json` while the error mentions the response(?) content having the media type `text/html`. If i were you, that's where i would start with my trouble-shooting first; why is the response "text/html" instead of the requested "application/json"? (If i were to speculate, i would guess that if the server fails to process the request, it sends some error response in `text/html` form. But that's just me speculating, it is up to you to look hard at what is going on there between your program and the server)

Comment: Never use `.Wait()`. If the code must be sync, use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead

Comment: Thank you both! The problem is solved. As Elgonzo suggested it was a 50X error from the server. I solved it implementing Polly. Additionally, I got the.Wait() out of my code. Thanks again!